# How to customize keys in operator key map?

Tags: modeling, shortcut, keymap

Is it possible to customize your keys in an operator?

For example, this is the Inset key map, and I want to change some keys in it.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible without modifying the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This overlay shows the key map of any currently running operator.

Unfortunately, there is no way to change these for now, they are hard-coded in Blender.

The only thing you can customize is the default settings when you run the operator:

[image]

To learn more: [Keymap Customization — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/keymap_editing.html)

Comment: That's so sad... Alright, thanks for help